# How to swap one single LED for two color one that will change color depending on state

Tags: led, led-driver

I have a display for an alarm system, which drives LEDs with 7mA current source.
It will toggle between on and not connected, according to the state of the alarm system.

What I'm trying to do is to build an add-on for the LED, that will make it drive a second LED when first one is off (and use one two-color diode for that if possible, but two separate LEDs will do)

The driver uses constant current, so I think that a not gate won't work in this setup.

I'm trying to do this as simply as possible, since there is few dozen LEDs that I would like to replace on the panel.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Do you have a schematic for the driver circuit? It matters.

Comment: Sadly, no, it's a commercial board: https://www.satel.pl/en/produktid/35 All I have are the specs.

Comment: What is the part number on the driver chips?

Answer (score 1):

A simple circuit like this should work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdRSCn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use the LED current to activate a transistor base (Q2). when it's on, D1 will sink the current and Q1 can't be activated.

When Q2 is off, your constant current source activates Q1 base and D2 will light up.

The circuit toggles between D1 and D2 based on Q2 status.

Comment: Both LEDs will be on or only D2. You won't get D1 on without D2 being on.

Comment: @Andyaka It's working in the simulator ([link](http://tinyurl.com/y4gnq77t)) and I have tried it before in one of my projects.

Comment: If D2 is red it is likely to have a lower on voltage and may activate if D1 is a different color type that requires a different terminal voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka Can't we avoid that by increasing Q1 base resistance?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can still use a NOT gate but to drive 2 separate transistors from the Alarm signal

[image]